# center align position absolute object horizontally

Tags: css

i have an element whose position is absolute the only issue i am facing is i have applied some properties to align it center horizontally and it is working fine on mozilla but the same properties are not working on chrome
here's my code

**html**

```
<a href="#section1" class="scrollTo downarrow"><img src="images/navbar_downarrow.png" class="img-responsive"/></a>
```

**css**

```
    .slider{
        position: relative;
        background-image: url("../images/slider.jpg");
        background-size: 100% 100%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
    .slider a.downarrow{
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 20px;
        display: table;
    }
```

Comment: yup removed it mistyped it

Comment: Do you know the width of downarrow?

Comment: width:100% for chrome but still work

Comment: it seems you need to specify width to `.slider`, e.g. `width: 100vw;`

Comment: no it is taking the with of whole screen

Comment: Very useful guide: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Answer (score 39, accepted):

A useful trick to center elements is to use the `transform: translate` style together with either `top`, `margin-left` `left` or `margin-top`.

To answer your question, you have to apply the following styles to your `.slider a.downarrow` element:

```
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

---

The way this works is because if `translate` is used with a percentage value, its value is calculated based on the elements height/width on which it is applied on.

`top`, `margin-left` `left` and `margin-top` percentage values are calculated based on the parent element or in case the element has `position: absolute` applied to it based on the nearest parent with `position: relative/absolute`.

To center an element you just need to apply a value of `50%` to either `top`, `margin-left` `left` or `margin-top` and a value of `-50%` to `translate`.

For `left` and `margin-left` you have to use `translateX(-50%)` and for the others `translateY(-50%)`.

**EDIT:** Added an explanation

Comment: Wow, this was quite a find.  Thank you both for the question and the answer.  Saved my life!

Comment: One notable caveat to this method is that the size will only grow to 50% of the positioned parent's width. If you need larger than that you must define a width for the div.